# In Java RMI Naming.rebind(url,obj) ,what is the parameter of obj?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm searching on using the java rmi, but i found some code confusing like this:

```
public class RmiServer{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
    int port = 1099;
    String url = "rmi://localhost:1099/HelloServiceImpl";
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
    Naming.rebind(url, new HelloServiceImpl());
    System.out.println("already create remote service:" + url);
 }
}
```

But the parameter "new HelloServiceImpl()" is just a original object instantce .It's not a stub! How could this code rebind the stub to registry?
As we can see in Name.rebind :

```
public static void rebind(String name, Remote obj)
    throws RemoteException, java.net.MalformedURLException
{
    ParsedNamingURL parsed = parseURL(name);
    Registry registry = getRegistry(parsed);

    if (obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("cannot bind to null");

    registry.rebind(parsed.name, obj);
}
```

It passes the obj to registry not the stub!
Could anyone help me to get the answer?

By the way ,the HelloServiceImpl like this :

```
public class HelloServiceImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements      HelloService
 {

public HelloServiceImpl() throws RemoteException
{
}

@Override
public String sayHello(String name) throws RemoteException
{
    return String.format("Hello %s", name);
}
}
```

Comment: Don't post code in comments. You should be able to see for yourself that it is completely illegible. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an exported remote object as an RMI parameter or result passes the stub instead. This is automatic.

Comment: It's done automatically by extending `ObjectOutputStream` and overriding `writeReplace().`

Comment: Well Have got it !Sincerely great thanks to u for your excellent replies!